# Echoing data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, count, echo, addition

I have a Table in MySQL that stores data as such:

```
Name      Amount   Time

Person 1    1      Time
Person 2    1      Time
Person 3    1      Time
Person 1    1      Time
Person 2    1      Time
Person 3    1      Time
Person 1    1      Time
```

I want to echo these reults so they would add all the 'amounts' together and put the final number with the persons name so it would appear as:

```
 Person 1    3    Time
 Person 2    2    Time
 Person 3    2    Time
```

How can I do this in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Think *aggregate* functions http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx and `GROUP BY`

Comment: Don't do it in PHP.  let the database aggregate the results for you; far faster than you can code it.  General rule let database aggregate results, let PHP render it and make it look pretty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Total up MySQL Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717266/total-up-mysql-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that in sql instead of in php.

Something like:

```
SELECT `Name`, SUM(`Amount`) as total, `Time` FROM `your_table` GROUP BY `Name`
```